# getting a null pointing exception in eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, class, nullpointerexception

When I try to call the `AddGrade` method in the student class, which uses the `AddGrade` in the Grades class I get a `NullPointerException`.
It says I have to add more details which I'm not sure why.

Class One is

```
public class Grades {
private double qualPts;
private int numCreds;

public Grades() {

}   
/**
 * Returns the GPA
 */
public double getGPA()
{
    if (numCreds>0)
    return qualPts/numCreds;
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Adds the new grade's credits
 * Weights the newly added grade
 */
public void addGrade(int creds, double grade)
{
 numCreds+=creds;
 qualPts+=creds*grade;
}
/**
 * Returns the number of credits
 */
public int getNumCred()
{
    return numCreds;
}

}
```

Class 2 is

```
Public class Student 
{
private String name;
private String bNumber;
private Grades grades;

public Student(String name, String bNumber) {
this.name=name;
this.bNumber=bNumber;
}   
/**
 * adds the new grade's credits
 * weights the new grade
 */
public void addGrade(int creds, double grade)
{
    grades.addGrade(creds,grade);

}
```

}

Comment: Look at `Student.grades`. Look at it long and hard. You also asked this yesterday.

Comment: Also, look at using a debugger and walking through your code to learn how it works.

Comment: In addition to that, you should always append the full stack trace when asking about exceptions you'Re getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor in the Student class, you need to create an instance of Grades.

```
public Student(String name, String bNumber) {
this.name=name;
this.bNumber=bNumber;
this.grades = new Grades();
}
```

Otherwise `this.grades` is null, because it is never set to another value.

Answer (score 1):

grades was never instantiated.  You can do that on the declaration.

Grades is a class (a reference type) value types (aka primitives: int,bool,long etc...) don't need to be instantiated.  String is a reference type but the compiler allows you to declare them in a similar way as you declare value types.  To boil it down if you write a class you MUST call one of it's constructors if you want to use it.

```
public class Student 
{
  private String name;
  private String bNumber;
  private Grades grades = new Grades();

  public Student(String name, String bNumber) {
    this.name=name;
    this.bNumber=bNumber;
  }   
  /**
  * adds the new grade's credits
  * weights the new grade
  */
  public void addGrade(int creds, double grade)
  {
    grades.addGrade(creds,grade);

  } 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

One problem could be that you have not initialized two variables in the Grade class but have used the numCreds+=creds and qualPts+=creds*grade;

```
public void addGrade(int creds, double grade)
 {
   numCreds+=creds;
   qualPts+=creds*grade;
 }
```

Comment: Those fields are primitives.  They don't cause null pointer exceptions.